# spring-cloud-starter-zuul memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, tomcat8, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We are using:

1. spring-cloud-starter-zuul:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE
2. spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE
3. embedded tomcat version: 8.0.43
4. Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_101
5. spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar:1.2.6.RELEASE

After running load tests on our zuul gateway, we are observing the increase in memory being currently consumed:

pcf metrics:

[image]

I did a heapdump before and after load test. The biggest increase in not collected objects we noted:

heap dump after load test:

[image]

It looks like those objects are responsible (or are) for requests for some static data, which lives in one of the micro services behind zuul proxy.

Our zuul is vanilla one without any custom code.

We googled a little and tried to follow [this](http://www.evanjones.ca/java-bytebuffer-leak.html), and configured `Djdk.nio.maxCachedBufferSize=262144` in `JAVA_OPTS` but without any effect.

Our stress tests are using gatling. It's report says all the requested completed with OK status (11 KO - those are AWS S3 images time outs, which are not going through our zuul)

This looks like a memory leak, but we can not find where?

Comment: Gatling test results:https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdGCb.png